# Facebook Graph API to send message to friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I had read the [API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/), but still not sure if it's possible to send message to a friend? Suppose I had get access_token from user.

I want to use the API to display user's friends list in my Web UI, and the user can choose a friend and start to chat with the one.

Comment: No that is not possible